# Should a new VertexBuffer3D & IndexBuffer3D be created for each Program3D used?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, instantiation, vertex-buffer, stage3d

If I have a few `Program3D` objects (each with it's own **Vertex-Shader** and **Fragment-Shader** responsible for it's own rendering task), do I need to instantiate a new `VertexBuffer3D` and `IndexBuffer3D` so that they store the data only relevant to the vertex-data format used by their corresponding `Program3D`?

For example, if I was planning to define Quads in different vertex-data formats, such as:

```
var vertexData:Vector.<Number>;

//Vertex-Format A:
vertexData = new <Number>[
  //X, Y, U, V
  -.5, -.5, 0, 0,
  .5, -.5, 1, 0,
  .5, .5, 1, 1,
  -.5, .5, 0, 1
];

//Vertex-Format B:
vertexData = new <Number>[
  //X, Y, U, V, Matrix-Constant ID, Color
  -.5, -.5, 0, 0, 3, 0xff0000,
  .5, -.5, 1, 0 , 3, 0x00ff00,
  .5, .5, 1, 1,   3, 0x0000ff,
  -.5, .5, 0, 1,  3, 0xffff00
];

//Vertex-Format C:
vertexData = new <Number>[
  //X, Y, Matrix-Constant ID
  -.5, -.5, 3,
  .5, -.5, 3,
  .5, .5, 3,
  -.5, .5, 3
];
```

Would I need to create one `VertexBuffer3D` and `IndexBuffer3D` to store ***format A***, another one for ***format B***, and yet another one for ***format C***? Or can the various formats be mixed inside the same `VertexBuffer3D` and then make some clever (or confusing!) use of a single `IndexBuffer3D` to draw the triangles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix and match freely. Think of a vertex program needing all inputs hooked up to something. Where that is comming from is done with setVertexBufferAt. It can come from different buffer, it can come even from the same location. Just like connecting some wires. Index buffers just jump around in the vertex buffers. You can, and should, re-use them as much as possible.